# DAW Instruction capabilites

Tags: assembly, pic18

I know that the DAW instruction adjusts the 8bit result in the WREG after adding two packed BCD numbers but is the DAW instruction capable of adjusting a much higher bit result in WREG ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @ErikEidt I dont have software to try it. I am being lectured with powerpoint slides.

Comment: Well that's probably the first thing you should fix.  If you want to learn assembly for any ISA, get a simulator (or real hardware with a working debugger) so you can single-step any instruction you're wondering about.  And so you can assemble or disassemble stuff if you want to know what's legal or look at the machine code.  If there's any ambiguity you're wondering about in the docs, you can always test.

Answer (score 2):

During an `ADDWF` or a `SUBWF` the `DC` (digit carry) flag captures the carry out from bit 3 during addition, while the `C` (carry) flag captures the carry out from bit 7 during addition. Carries in subtraction are generated based on x - y = x + NOT (y) + 1, where NOT is the one's complement. This means the value of these carry flags is the *complement* of the respective borrows.

`DAW` adds 6 to the least significant nibble of `W`, i.e. `W<3:0>`, if the nibble's value is greater than 9, **or** `DC` is set.
`DAW` adds 6 to the most significant nibble of `W`, i.e. `W<7:4>`, if the nibble's value is greater than 9, **or** `C` is set.

If two nibbles representing BCD digits are added, the resulting nibble value is in [0x0, 0x12], which is why two conditions need to be combined to detect a decimal carry out from that nibble. For example, when we add `0x99` to `0x99`, the sum is `0x32`, and `DC`=1 and `C`=1, since 0x9 + 0x9 = `0x12` meaning there is a carry out from each nibble. Because both flags are set, a following `DAW` adds 6 to each nibble, resulting in `0x98`, which is the correct BCD result.

The `DAW` instruction simply follows the above rules and has no way of knowing whether the content of the `W` register and the flags are actually the result of the addition of two BCD digits. So lets assume we add `0xee` (not a valid BCD number) and `0x11`, resulting in `0xff`. Both `DC` and `C` will be zero. A following `DAW` will find that each nibble is greater than 9, and add 6 to each nibble, resulting in `0x55`.